# R: error in UseMethod(select_)-> no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "factor"

Tags: r, input, compiler-errors, statistics

I start this command

```
 select(FASCIA_ETA,stato)%>% 
    group_by(FASCIA_ETA) %>% 
    count(stato) %>% 
    mutate(statoRate=100*round(n/sum(n),2))
```

but the error is: `no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "factor"`

The input are:

```
FASCIA_ETA  :Factor w/ 9 levels "da 0 a 24 anni",..: 5 5 7 3 4 3 5 4 4 5 ...
and stato  : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

What is the solution of this error?
Thank you.

Comment: you need to use summarise function before count

Comment: Thank you, but what Is the script that I had to use?

Comment: can u dput() data? or any sample data